# How to save UTF-8 data in MySQL database in Livecode app

Tags: mysql, utf-8, send, livecode

I'm trying to save some data gathered from fields in MySQL db. Text contains some Polish characters, but Livecode sends all Polish chars as '?'. Here's part of my code:

1. Declare variable

   put the unicodeText of field "Title" into tTitle
   put uniEncode(tTitle, "UTF8") into tTitle
2. Send this to db:

   put "UPDATE magazyn SET NAZWA='" & tTitle & "'" into tSQLStatement
   revExecuteSQL gConnectionID,tSQLStatement, "SET NAMES 'utf8'"

For example, word "łąka" is saved as "??ka". I've tried uniEncode, uniDecode, everything is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use any encoders/decoders.  They will only add to the confusion.

When trying to use utf8/utf8mb4, if you see **Question Marks** (regular ones, not black diamonds),

- The bytes to be stored are not encoded as utf8.  Fix this.  (Getting rid of the encoders may fix it.)
- The column in the database is `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4).  Fix this.
- Also, check that the connection during reading is utf8.  I don't know the details of "Livecode"; look in its documentation.  If you can't find anything, execute this SQL after connecting: `SET NAMES utf8`.

Comment: Rick, how do I use CHARACTER SET utf8 ? And if you look at my code, I've used SET NAMES. Do I have to put it in opening connection to db code?

Comment: Look at the table schema (`SHOW CREATE TABLE` or equivalent); it may say `CHARACTER SET ...` on the column definition, or it may only say it on the table definition.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the column in the database is set to utf8 encoding.

Starting with LiveCode 7 *all* text in fields is unicode, specifically UTF-16. Before you send the text out to any external file or datastore, you need to encode it as UTF-8 (or whatever format you want to store it in. Use the LiveCode textEncode() function for this:

```
put textEncode(field "Title","utf-8") into tTitle
put "UPDATE magazine SET nazwa = :1" into tSQLStatement
revExecuteSQL gConnectionID, tSQLStatement, "tTitle"
```

Note: It's also a good idea to use the :N variable substitution method to reduce the risk of SQL code injection attacks.

When you read the data from the database use `textDecode` to convert back to UTF-16:

```
put textDecode(tRawDataFromDB,"UTF-16") into old tTitle
```

Comment: All columns and db are utf8_general_ci. I've tried uniEncode, still nothing :/

Comment: My apologies, I made a mistake in my code. Use the textEncode function, not uniEncode, which is deprecated. I've edited my code example to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Here's code:

```
get the unicodeText of field "Title"
```

put unidecode(it,"polish") into tTitle

it will save polish characters in a strange version, but for downloading i'm using this code:

```
set the unicodetext of fld "List" to uniencode(tList,"polish")
```

tList variable contains all data gathered from MySQL